# Get request for bearer token

Tags: .net, api, oauth-2.0

The object is to recieve a bearer token from the requested API. I was able to complete this using postman but would like to implement into my app.

I have attempted many different variations of calls but this one seems like I am closest with. I am currently getting status code: 400 bad request when using the below script.

Does anyone have any ideas to resolve this?

```
Dim credentials As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user & ":" + password))

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://oauth2.url.com/token")
        request.Proxy = Nothing
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Headers.Add("client_id", "clientid")
        request.Headers.Add("client_secret", "clientsecret")
        request.Headers.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
        request.Headers.Add("auth_url", "https://oauth2.url.com/authorization")
        request.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = "Basic " & credentials
        request.Headers.Add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5000/auth/callback")

        'create the response and reader
        Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
        Dim ResponseStream As System.IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream

        'Create Stream reader
        Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(ResponseStream)
        Dim data As String = StreamReader.ReadToEnd
        StreamReader.Close()

        'get the data
        Dim jsonString = data.ToString.Replace("'", "''")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the example from [this](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/authorization-code-request/) page, you must use `POST` instead of `GET`. 
Another problem is that you are sending all the parameters in your HTTP request's headers instead of simply putting them in the request's body.

Comment: I changed to a post command but still no luck. I have been researching the past few days on changing these parameters to request body but nothing comes up to what I am I looking for. Could you provide an example?